# Geometrical independence vs linear independence.

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology

In Element of Algebraic Topology by James R. Munkres, It's said that a set of point $\{a_0,\dots,a_n\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^N$ is geometrically independent if
$$ \sum_{i=0}^n t_i = 0\ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ \sum_{i=0}^n t_i a_i = 0 $$
implies that $t_0 = t_1 = \dots = t_n = 0$.

I understand the concept of linear independence,but a don't get why you have to put the condition $\sum_{i=0}^n t_i = 0$ in there to get the geometrical independence.

Comment: Choose an $a_i$ and consider the $n$ vectors $a_0-a_i,\dots,a_{i-1}-a_i,a_{i+1}-a_i,\dots,a_n-a_i$ (ommiting the zero vector). Then $\{a_0,\dots,a_n\}$ is geometrically independent if and only if $\{a_0-a_1,\dots,a_n-a_i\}$ is linearly independent. Consider what the linear indepence conditions for this new set requires of the coefficients in terms of the old set.

Comment: What you are saying, I know is a consequence of the definition that I stated in the question, and not the inverse. Because in the book, that exactly what comes next.

Comment: Note that it's an *if and only if* statement. The point is that if $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_k\in\mathbb{R}^N$ are geometrically independent, then there is a unique k-dimensional hyperplane $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ containing all these points. If $V$ is the linear span of the linearly independent set $a_1-a_0,\dots,a_k-a_0$, then $A=V+a_0$. The condition you are asking about is just another way to express this fact.

Comment: the $n$ in $a_n$ is not the $n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ right ?